# How to split "";"" java

Tags: java, string, split

Im trying to split the string using

```
String str = str.split("";"")
```

the problem is that because I need to split using something that contains `"` it wont recognize it as one string.
what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java you should use:

```
String str = str.split("\";\"");
```

to escape the " character.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is called "escaping" if im not mistaken,y ou can do what you want to do using Regular expressions.

There was a simular question on here already: [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

I find the explanation with the checkmark pretty good, if you want i can explain it to with my words though